# How to Delete Custom links in Site Action Menu @SharePoint 2013

Tags: custom-actions, menu

[image]

In Gear Menu(Site Action Menu) i created custom Menu Using JavaScript CSOM. now i want to delete those Custom site action menus. so please let me show how i delete it.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script  Language="JavaScript">

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("GetUserCustomActionSite");

var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
var collUserCustomAction;
var clientContext;
var oWebsite;

function GetUserCustomActionSite() {
    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
    collUserCustomAction = oWebsite.get_userCustomActions();

    clientContext.load(oWebsite, 'Title', 'UserCustomActions');

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(DeleteCustomAction, OnQueryFailed);
}

function DeleteCustomAction()
{
    var customActionEnumerator = collUserCustomAction.getEnumerator();

    while (customActionEnumerator.moveNext()) 
    {
        var oUserCustomAction = customActionEnumerator.get_current();

        if (oUserCustomAction.get_title() == 'ITSD Admin1') 
        {
           oUserCustomAction.deleteObject();
       clientContext.load(oUserCustomAction);
       clientContext.executeQueryAsync(OnQuerySucceeded,OnQueryFailed);
        }
    }
}

function OnQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    alert('Custom action deleted for ' + this.oWebsite.get_title());
}

function OnQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide some context/explanation ?

Comment: You should clear some things up about your answer, otherwise it may be deleted. What does the code do? Where to put it? Simply pasting a piece of non formatted code won't help to much.